# How do I remove the VGA port off a HD 5450 to make it low-profile?

Tags: graphics-card, vga

I want to remove the VGA port on my HD 5450 but I do not know how. I know it can be done but I do not know how. I want to make it low-profile so it can fit in a half-height case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

This seems to be one of those cards .

Looks like a standard ribbon cable - you should just be able to pull it straight up off the board.. You'd just need to disconnect it from the video card side (simple). You'd then want to carefully undo the two nuts in front of your video card, which is what's holding the VGA port in place - I usually just use a pair of needle nose pliers.  You'd then either need to find an appropriate low profile bracket or modify it for your case, but that's going to involve lots of measurements, maybe a dremel and a cutoff wheel and other such malarchy.